# How do I get a list of specific tags in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

So I basically want to get data for specific tags that I search for. I want to search the room tags via the `gridnumber`. Eg if I give the input 0, I want to search `gridnum` tag with the value 0 in the room tags. And after it finds the matching tag I want to be able to return the nested data for that specific tag (room). Input 0 should search and find tag `gridnum` with value 0 and return value for `name`, `floor`, and all other tags as well that are nested in that room tag. Including a list of `mac-addresses` inside the tag.

I've tried using this way:

```java
InputStream is = mycontext.getAssets().open("indoor.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
element.normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("room");
```

But I dont have much knowledge of XML so i dont know how to go ahead with it. Id appreciate if anyone could help me out.

This is the XML file:

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
  <room-info>
    <room>
      <gridnum>0</gridnum>
      <name>G-04</name>
      <floor>1</floor>
      <category>Class</category>
      <mac-addresses>
        <mac>58B6330C6EC8=47</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C6DF4=39</mac>
        <mac>58B6330CJ788=35</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C67GG=30</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C0099=25</mac>
      </mac-addresses>
      </room>
      <room>
      <gridnum>1</gridnum>
      <name>G-04</name>
      <floor>1</floor>
      <category>Class</category>
      <mac-addresses>
        <mac>58B6330C6EC8=47</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C6DF4=39</mac>
        <mac>58B6330CJ788=35</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C67GG=30</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C0099=25</mac>
      </mac-addresses>
      </room>
      <room>
      <gridnum>2</gridnum>
      <name>G-04</name>
      <floor>1</floor>
      <category>Class</category>
      <mac-addresses>
        <mac>58B6330C6EC8=47</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C6DF4=39</mac>
        <mac>58B6330CJ788=35</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C67GG=30</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C0099=25</mac>
      </mac-addresses>
      </room>
      <room>
      <gridnum>3</gridnum>
      <name>G-04</name>
      <floor>1</floor>
      <category>Class</category>
      <mac-addresses>
        <mac>58B6330C6EC8=47</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C6DF4=39</mac>
        <mac>58B6330CJ788=35</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C67GG=30</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C0099=25</mac>
      </mac-addresses>
      </room>
      <room>
      <gridnum>4<gridnum>
      <name>G-04</name>
      <floor>1</floor>
      <category>Accounts</category>
      <mac-addresses>
        <mac>58B6330C6EC8=47</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C6DF4=39</mac>
        <mac>58B6330CJ788=35</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C67GG=30</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C0099=25</mac>
      </mac-addresses>
      </room>
      <room>
      <gridnum>5</gridnum>
      <name>G-04</name>
      <floor>1</floor>
      <category>Accounts</category>
      <mac-addresses>
        <mac>58B6330C6EC8=47</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C6DF4=39</mac>
        <mac>58B6330CJ788=35</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C67GG=30</mac>
        <mac>58B6330C0099=25</mac>
      </mac-addresses>
      </room>
  </room-info>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `XPath` simplifies this type of work.
Read more about `XPath` [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath).

This is how it can be applied for to your xml.

```
FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream("indoor.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(fileIS);

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/room-info/room[gridnum=" + "'" + GRID_NUM + "'" + "]";
Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
```